# Moisture Sensor with MicaZ board

Tags: sensors, iot, contiki

I am creating a project using MicaZ boards. It has a sensor board MD100. I want to attach a moisture sensor with that board. We are using Contiki to program the board.

What I know so far is that, out of the 4 pins of sensor, VCC will be at one of the VCC port, GND will be to any one ground port, I don't want to use digital O/P, hence d0 won't be connected. And the last A0 the analog pic is connected to ADC7 pin of Md100.

In the program, I using the function adc_init() and then to read value I m using get_adc(7) where 7 denotes the channel. I am not getting any correct value from sensor.

So I wanted to know where am I going wrong. 
PS: I am not sure that as I have attached sensor with ADC7 the channel no should be 7.

Thanks in advance.